# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) in LinkedList

Tags: initialization, singly-linked-list

I keep getting the Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) in Valgrind for the function printList() and freeList(). I read a few posts and the problem was because head was not initialized after malloc() so I added newList->head = NULL after malloc in my createList() function. I am not sure how to fix this error. Any help is really appreciated! I am really new to C so I really don't know what the problem is...

```
typedef struct node{
    int year;
    int win;
    struct node* next;
}node_t;

typedef struct slist{
        node_t* head;
        int size;
}slist_t;

node_t* makeNode(int year, int win){
        node_t* newNode = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        if (newNode == NULL){
            return NULL;
        }
        newNode->year = year;
        newNode->win = win; 
        return newNode;
}

void freeNode(node_t* node){
        if (node == NULL){
            return;
        }
        free(node);
}

slist_t* createList(){
    
        slist_t* newList = (slist_t*) malloc(sizeof(slist_t));
        
    if (newList == NULL){
            return;
    }   
    newList->head = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    newList->head = NULL;   
    newList->size = 0;
    return newList;
}

node_t*  addFirst(slist_t* list, int year, int win){
    node_t* node = makeNode(year, win); 
    
    if (list == NULL){
        return;
    }
    
    if (node == NULL){
        return;
    }
    if (list->head == NULL){
            list->head = node;
    }   
    else{
        node->next = list->head;
        list->head = node;
    }
    list->size += 1;
    return node;
}

void printList(slist_t* list){
    if (list == NULL){
        return;
    }
    node_t* itr = list->head;
    while(itr != NULL){
        printf("%d, %d wins\n", itr->year, itr->win);
        itr = itr->next;
    } 
    printf("\n");
}
void freeList(slist_t* list){
    node_t* node = list->head;
    while (node){
        node_t* temp = node;
        node = node->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    free(list); 
}
int main(){
    slist_t* list = createList();
    
    addFirst(list, 2014, 71);
    addFirst(list, 2015, 78);
    addFirst(list, 2016, 93);
    addFirst(list, 2017, 93);
    addFirst(list, 2018, 108); 

    printList(list);
    freeList(list);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question will get more attention when you tag it with `c` -- the most important tag for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `makeNode` does not initialise `newNode->next`. If it happens to have the value 0 (`NULL`), things will go fine, but try to add this statement in `makeNode` and then run the program:

```
newNode->next = 1000000;
```

Now it is more likely you get a segmentation fault or some other weird behaviour. So add this line instead:

```
newNode->next = NULL;
```

Not your issue, but this sequence of assignments produces a memory leak:

```
newList->head = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
newList->head = NULL;
```

After having allocated memory, you immediately lose the reference to it, by overwriting that reference with `NULL`. You should just drop the first of these two assignments. The first node is created later, when you call `addFirst`, so no node should be allocated here.